# Values present in center of Card

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting response from api in which i get some values but my values shows in the center of card i just want to show then left side of card.

Code :

```
return Scaffold(
        body: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _itemcount,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return new Container(
                child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Card(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Text("next"),
                              new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0)),
                              new Text("previous")
                            ],
                          ),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }));
```

My recent View :

[image: My output]

Comment: Have you tried `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` for the Column?

Comment: isn't it makes card small than other things i want on stretched card but text at left side

Comment: You could try to wrap your `Column` inside a `Row`

Comment: see my answer, I've tested it, it gives me the text on the left of each card

Comment: @JulienLachal I've completed thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _itemcount,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Container(
          child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                ),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text("next"),
                          new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0)),
                          new Text("previous")
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      })
    );
```

By wrapping the `Column` in a `Row` it pushes content to the left of the `Card`